# How to display one picture in this ad? Laravel 4

Tags: php, html, image, laravel

I have problem with displayin one picture in my home page.

Currently, I loaded some photos. I created a column in the database 'thumbnail'. Wants to do so, to load the photo - thumbnail where the column 'thumbnail
 have record =  1.

My Homecontroller:

```
    public function getHome(){ 
    return View::make('pages.home')
        ->with('offers', Offer::take(8)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get());

    }
```

my view:

```
@foreach($offers as $offer)

  <div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 1px solid #AADFFF; height:350px; ">

    @foreach($offer->photosofoffers as $photosofoffer)

        <a href="{{ route('pages.view', $offer->id) }}">
        <!--<a href="/pages/view/{{ $offer->id }}">-->
        {{ HTML::image($photosofoffer->file, $photosofoffer->title, array( 'class'=>'feature', 'width'=>'240', 'height'=>'127')) }}


        </a>
    @endforeach
        <h3><a href="{{ route('pages.view', $offer->id) }}">{{ $offer->title }}</h3>
        <p> {{ $offer->description }} </p>

        <h5>Availability: <span class="{{ Availability::displayClass($offer->availability) }}">
        {{ Availability::display($offer->availability) }}
        </span>
        </h5>

        <p>Cena <span>{{ $offer->price }}</span>
        </p>
```

@endforeach

Where should I add something?
At the moment loads all the images of the announcement. He wants to load one image, where the 'thumbnail' = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load the relations and apply a constraint.  Something like:

```
Offer::with(array('photosofoffers' => function($q) {
    $q->where('thumbnail', 1)->take(1);
}))->take(8)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

If you want to load only those offers that have a photo/thumbnail

```
Offer::with('photosoffers')->whereHas('photosofoffers', function($q) {
    $q->where('thumbnail', 1)->take(1);
})->take(8)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```